# How to resize the ClipPath area of SVG?

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I have such code:

```css
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clipped-img {
  clip-path: url('#header-clip-svg');
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">

  <!--clipping SVG-->
  <svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="header-clip-svg">
        <path d="M199.6,18.9c-4.3-8.9-12.5-16.4-22.3-17.8c-11.9-1.7-23.1,5.4-32.2,13.2c-9.1,7.8-17.8,16.8-29.3,20.3c-20.5,6.2-41.7-7.4-63.1-7.5C38.7,27,24.8,33,15.2,43.3c-35.5,38.2-0.1,99.4,40.6,116.2c32.8,13.6,72.1,5.9,100.9-15c27.4-19.9,44.3-54.9,47.4-88.6c0.2-2.7,0.4-5.3,0.5-7.9C204.8,38,203.9,27.8,199.6,18.9z"></path>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>

  <!-- clipped image-->
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3341051/team.jpg"/>
  
</div>
```

I want to increase the clipping shape dimensions so it will be of the width of colored green area. Is there a way to do achieve this?

Comment: Not without updating the SVG. I notice it does not have a `viewbox`, I'd start there.

Comment: @Paulie_D could you please add an answer with updated SVG?

Comment: I'm not in a position to rewrite the SVG, that's something you'd have to do.

Comment: @Paulie_D you meant editing path, not attributes? If yes, sorry, I didn't mean to ask path editing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can apply the SVG as a `mask` and easily adjust its size and position (like you can with `background-image`). Simply make sure you set the correct value for the viewbox:

```css
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen; 
  margin:5px;
}

.clipped-img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  object-fit:cover;
  -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 207 167"><path d="M199.6,18.9c-4.3-8.9-12.5-16.4-22.3-17.8c-11.9-1.7-23.1,5.4-32.2,13.2c-9.1,7.8-17.8,16.8-29.3,20.3c-20.5,6.2-41.7-7.4-63.1-7.5C38.7,27,24.8,33,15.2,43.3c-35.5,38.2-0.1,99.4,40.6,116.2c32.8,13.6,72.1,5.9,100.9-15c27.4-19.9,44.3-54.9,47.4-88.6c0.2-2.7,0.4-5.3,0.5-7.9C204.8,38,203.9,27.8,199.6,18.9z"></path></svg>' ) 
               center/contain no-repeat;
          mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 207 167"><path d="M199.6,18.9c-4.3-8.9-12.5-16.4-22.3-17.8c-11.9-1.7-23.1,5.4-32.2,13.2c-9.1,7.8-17.8,16.8-29.3,20.3c-20.5,6.2-41.7-7.4-63.1-7.5C38.7,27,24.8,33,15.2,43.3c-35.5,38.2-0.1,99.4,40.6,116.2c32.8,13.6,72.1,5.9,100.9-15c27.4-19.9,44.3-54.9,47.4-88.6c0.2-2.7,0.4-5.3,0.5-7.9C204.8,38,203.9,27.8,199.6,18.9z"></path></svg>' ) 
               center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800">
</div>

<div class="img-container" style="width:500px;">
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800">
</div>

<div class="img-container" style="width:150px;">
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800">
</div>
```

[image: CSS mask with SVG clip-path]

Comment: In my situation svg code will dynamic than what can do? i can't put in css like what you gave solution.

Comment: @JigneshPanchal you mean what by *dynamic*? in all the cases you simply need to put the SVG inside the mask, whataver the SVG

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409895/css-property-mask-is-not-working-properly-for-svg

Answer (score 0):

```css
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clipped-img {
  clip-path: url('#header-clip-svg');
      max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">

  <!--clipping SVG-->
  <svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="header-clip-svg">
        <path d="M199.6,18.9c-4.3-8.9-12.5-16.4-22.3-17.8c-11.9-1.7-23.1,5.4-32.2,13.2c-9.1,7.8-17.8,16.8-29.3,20.3c-20.5,6.2-41.7-7.4-63.1-7.5C38.7,27,24.8,33,15.2,43.3c-35.5,38.2-0.1,99.4,40.6,116.2c32.8,13.6,72.1,5.9,100.9-15c27.4-19.9,44.3-54.9,47.4-88.6c0.2-2.7,0.4-5.3,0.5-7.9C204.8,38,203.9,27.8,199.6,18.9z"></path>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
  <!-- clipped image-->
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3341051/team.jpg"/>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what your answer's code does; how it's different from OP's and how that difference solves the problem. Code-only answers are of little value.