# css property mask is not working properly for svg

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path, css-mask

Css property `clip-path` is work fine but `mask` or `-webkit-mask` is not working properly in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jigneshpanchalmj/cz3p92ob/13/).

Please help me to solve this because my project is totally depended on masking image with svg file.

In `clip-path`, i can't resize image in responsive views so i have only one way to solve this problem.

So please check example code , may be i have made any mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reduce your SVG code and remove all the `g` element to keep only the path like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/hro4wbzf/

Then you use this inside the `mask` and you do the rotation with CSS if needed:

https://jsfiddle.net/7kyazn30/

Related: [How to resize ClipPath area of SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60491855/8620333)

Answer (score 1):

For a huge online svg, I recommend you use the tag   ...  , instead of passing it entirely in the url() property of your css as you did. The risk of error is greater. So here's what I suggest.

```
<mask  id="maskMaskSource" class="MaskType" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<svg> .... </svg>
</mask>
```

And in your css:

```
#maskMaskSource {
mask-image: url(#maskMaskSource);
}
.MaskType {
mask-type: alpha;
}
```

You can get a more detailed explanation here: https://lab.iamvdo.me/css-svg-masks/#testM7

Comment: You can do a mask inline so there must be something wrong with the syntax he's using because it certainly is possible.

Comment: Maybe is possible, but I think that better to use html tag, for very huge inline svg.. @RobertLongson