# Inverted Clipping Mask (Sine Wave) - With CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, mask, clip

I want to create a clipping mask with an SVG (or CSS Polygon) but Instead of SHOWING what is represented by the SVG, I want the SVG to "Clip" the `<div>` and hide what is represented by the SVG.

So See the following picture, I'd like to create a sine wave at the bottom of pictures on mobile so the image (which is a background image) gets clipped with a sine wave at the bottom.

I've spent tons of time with `clip-path` and masking but nothing seems to do it. Since `clip-path` can't do curves it doesn't seem to work which is why I'm using an SVG.

[image]

Comment: And where is your starting point in code?

Comment: please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818192/how-to-add-path-to-a-clip-path/64818588#64818588

Comment: I found this tool that allows to do wave with `clip-path` : https://github.com/Svetloslav15/wave-generator, but imho the tool could be much improved. I also searched solutions with mask-image with no luck (since like you I want the mask image to act as an alpha channel)