# Put a responsive SVG with background-image

Tags: css, wordpress, image, svg

I make a website, and actually i have a simple rectangular images.

I want to design my image and make a design like below.

So i tried to create a svg, and i wanted to put my picture inside .. but the problem is that svg cant be responsive.

- Can i do it in full css ?
- Or it's better to use a SVG ?

The best way could be to use Photoshop and design the picture, but if i can make it in css or using svg, it's better. i know that some website have similar design for their pictures, how they do ?

[image]

Comment: Why SVG can't be responsive? If you saw similar image in other site(s), just take a look into they source code how it's done.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492086/8620333