# Implement clip-path for SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I have this svg:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1500 1417.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1500 1417.9;" xml:space="preserve">
<path class="st0" d="M551.5,13.4c0,0,427.5-20.4,781.6,329.6s12.8,677.8-16.5,705.6c-29.4,27.8-418.3,370.4-800,340.7
    S15.9,887.4,7.6,652.2S131.4,13.4,551.5,13.4z"/>
</svg>
```

I am trying to insert an image on the svg via clip-path:

```html
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 1500 1417.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1500 1417.9;" xml:space="preserve">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="shape">
            <path class="st0" d="M551.5,13.4c0,0,427.5-20.4,781.6,329.6s12.8,677.8-16.5,705.6c-29.4,27.8-418.3,370.4-800,340.7
            S15.9,887.4,7.6,652.2S131.4,13.4,551.5,13.4z"/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image height="100%" width="100%" clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="https://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/styles/article_main_large/public/dogs_1280p_0.jpg" ></image>
</svg>
```

The sides of the image are cutted off, what am i doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492086/8620333 (use it as mask)

Comment: the image is too small - smaller than the clipping path. Try `<image width="2000"` and no height

Comment: Thank you, i solved by removing height="100%" from <image>